# Vuejs How to get original array value back

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

vuejs:

I have main Object array

`testArray`

```
[ __ob__: Observer]
{
 `id` => 23,
 `value` => 65674 
}
{
 `id` => 20,
 `value` => 23423 
}
{
 `id` => 18,
 `value` => 55434 
}
{
 `id` => 22,
 `value` => 546464 
}
```

If I iterate and try to set the value of the array:

```
testArray.forEach((e2) => {
Vue.set(e2, 'value', 0);
});
```

The above code works and sets the value to `0` as per the `id`, However, this set the main array to `0` as well. How can the reset the value back t original state?

Do I have to clone the original array? How can I bring back the value without reloading the page?

Comment: I'm not familiar with vue syntax but you might have to create another property called `originalTestArray` to keep the initial array value. Whenever you want to reset, revert `testArray` array values back to `originalTestArray` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it will mutate the main array values as you are just creating a reference to the main array in the function and actually you are iterating over the original object.You will have to create a copy of the above object and mutate it keeping the original as it is.